# Google Sheets Script - Reference a specific cell in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where when I change a specific cell to "YES", I need a template sheet to be copied to a new version and named as per the value of a cell on the current row.

I'm having trouble working out how to get the value of the first cell in the row selected. This is what I have so far (I know this is wrong):

```
function onEdit() { 


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();  

  if (currentCell = "YES") 
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("New change control sheet added to workbook.","Change Control",15);

  var sourceRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var tabName = ss.getRange(cell,1).getValues();

    ss.getSheetByName("CCTemplate").showSheet()
    .activate();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('CCTemplate'), true);
    ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('CCTemplate'), true);
    ss.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Copy of CCTemplate'), true);
    ss.getActiveSheet().setName("CC" & tabName);
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell us which specific cell will you change to "YES"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) { 
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Your Sheet Name' && e.value=="YES") {
    e.source.toast="New change control sheet added to workbook.","Change Control",15);
    var tabName=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
    var tsh=e.source.getSheetByName('CCTemplate');
    var csh=tsh.copyTo(e.source);
    csh.setName('CC'+tabName);
  }
}
```

You should avoid using activate in your scripts especially  in simple triggers where you have to finish in 30 seconds. I think this code does the same thing that you intended for your code.  One significant difference is that I use the information that comes in the event object that comes with the trigger.  You  should add the code Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) and then look at the logs  you will  see that there is a lot of information available to you which removes the  need to run extra functions to get things like a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

`onEdit` offers among others the event objects `range` and `value` which are helpful to retrieve the range that has been edited and its value.

Also

- When you want to a cell  and compare it against a value, like in `if (currentCell = "YES")` - you need to retrive its value (either `currentCell.getValue()` or just `event.value`) and you need to use `==` instead of `=` for comparison.
- Be careful with `getValues()` vs `getValue()`. The former gives you a 2D array and is not necessary if you want to retrieve the value of a single cell.
- There is no need to set your sheet to active in order to change its name.

You can rewrite your code as following:

```
function onEdit(event) { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var currentCell = event.range;  
  var value = event.value;
  if (value == "YES") 
  {
    ...
    var sourceRow = range.getRowIndex();
    var tabName = ss.getRange(sourceRow, 1).getValue();
    ...
    ss.getSheetByName('Copy of CCTemplate').setName("CC" + tabName);
  }
}
```